# Does Android's WebView support HSTS?

Tags: android, android-security

Does Android WebView support HSTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, second this website: http://caniuse.com/#search=hsts since android 4.4

Main changes:

Certificate pinning

Trusted CA's

Add CA's to debug

Limit CA's

Add CA's hierarchy...

But the most important thing will be enabled on the new android **N** in an `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` like this:
https://koz.io/network-security-policy-configuration-for-android-apps/

```
<domain-config hstsEnforced=[True|False] cleartextTrafficPermitted=[True|False]>  
   <domain includeSubdomains=[True|False]>koz.io</domain>
   <pin-set expiration="exp-date">
     <pin digest=sha256>PaJOmDNhWkVBvuXfzqXMyfo7kgtGpcyZp6L8EqvM8Ck=</pin>
</pin-set>
```

This is the official documentation from google: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html