# how to add HSTS to a WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, hsts

I am trying to add HSTS to webview in my app, I tried editing network_security_config.xml as follows

```
<domain-config hstsEnforced = "true">
  <domain includeSubdomains="true">xxx.xxx.xxx</domain>
    <pin-set expiration="2019-05-24">
          <pin digest="SHA-256">sha_pin</pin>
     </pin-set>
</domain-config>
```

as described in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379933/does-androids-webview-support-hsts)

But still no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Android's WebView support HSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379933/does-androids-webview-support-hsts)

Comment: cod-e-rection :: I tried the solution mentioned in that answer but there is no impact of adding hsts setting in network_security_config.xml